# How to escape a closing tag in block comments /** */?

Tags: rust

I want to have an example regex in a comment:

```
/**
 * Example = ".*/full/.*" }}`
*/
pub fn my_fun() {}
```

I get a broken comment since `*/` is considered as ending the comment.

What would be a proper way to escape this so that some autogenerated docs don't display the escape character?

[image: Example from VSCode]

Comment: It's not really idiomatic to use block comments in the first place, so the simple answer is to use line comments.

Comment: Rust allows nested block comments, so a hack is to simply place `/*` before `Example` so that it matches up with `".*/full`

Comment: To expand on what Shepmaster said, Rust has a built-in documentation comment syntax: `/// Doc comment`.

Comment: I get all you guys are saying but still, does the language not support escaping this? I get that you could say you can use any character to escape since it changes nothing to the compiler but I was more wondering if there is an intended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
/**
 * Example = ".\*\/full/.*" }}
 */
pub fn my_fun(){}
```

It'll get rendered as

[image]

This should do.

But the recommended ways in rust are

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-04-comments.html
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-02-publishing-to-crates-io.html#making-useful-documentation-comments